# Biased coin probability when p can lie in a range of values

Tags: probability-distributions

I can't find anything like this problem online, any help would be greatly appreciated. This isn't homework, just a thought experiment I can't solve.

You are testing a new coin that is designed to land on heads greater than 70% of the time. How many times do you have to flip the coin to ensure it really does land on heads greater than 70% of the time at 90% level of confidence.